# How can I boot an OS, which only comes in floppy disk images, on a computer with only an SD card slot?

Tags: sd-card, bootable-media, disk-image

Particularly I'm talking about the [FSD Amoeba](http://fsd-amoeba.sourceforge.net/install.html) OS.

It comes as a set of 3 1/2" floppy disk images, but as today's systems don't feature floppy drives any more (in my case, I only have an SD card slot as external mass storage device), I wonder how I can get this image set (starting with the *COLDSTART* boot disk) on one single SD card to boot and install Amoeba from.

The official docs, unfortunately, contain no information on how to do it.

Comment: I *vaguely* remember grub can boot floppy images.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern computers can boot from USB devices.  This means you can purchase a [USB floppy drive](https://www.amazon.com/usb-floppy-drive/s?k=usb%20floppy%20drive) and boot from it.

If for some reason your computer cant boot from the USB floppy drive, you should be able to take an image of each floppy and write them to USB thumb drives.  I have done in this past (long, long ago) with [WinImage](https://www.winimage.com/).

Another possibility, would be to create a virtual machine, using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) as an example.  Create a VM, then install the OS using the USB floppy drive.  Then boot the VM off of an imaging tool like [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) and create an image of the OS.  Once you have the image, hopefully you can then write it to bare metal.